# How to edit several directories as one project in PyCharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

I created a django project and as it was recommended in django tutorial I placed static files like .js in separate folder as well as template directory.

The result structure is like:

```
MyProject >
  scripts # place for .py files
  static # .js, .jpg etc
  templates
```

Now when I open MyProject directory in PyCharm, it wants all imports starting with "scripts". Like `from scripts.myapp.mymodule import MyFunc`. But it is ugly.

Is it possible to open all 3 directories as one project or tell PyCharm where the sources are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings | Project Structure and mark the 'scripts' directory as a source root.